# Average gap between zeros on the critical strip of the Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, analytic-number-theory

Are there any approximations of the average gap between 2 successive zeros along the Riemann zeta functions critical strip up to the nth zero? If so, is it hypothesized that this average gap converges and if it doesn't then what does this mean for the primes?

Comment: The number of zeroes up to height $T$ is, asymptotically, ${T\over2\pi}\log{T\over2\pi}$.

Comment: (For more detail and references see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Number_of_zeros)

Comment: Also note that $(\gamma_2-\gamma_1)+(\gamma_3-\gamma_2)+...+(\gamma_n-\gamma_{n-1})=\gamma_n-\gamma_1$, so essentially you are just asking about the limit of $\gamma_n/n$ (which is zero, as follows from the above formula)

Comment: There is a lot of interest in the distribution of the gaps, see (for just one example) https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.4914.pdf for an overview.

Comment: I saw terence tao's lecture on youtube about the distribution of the gaps. He referred to these gaps as being either water, solid, or gas to specify that the gaps are either not equally space on the real line = water, on the real line and equally spaced = solid, or lie off the real line = gas. He also showed that the Riemann zeta function behaves like Bessel functions asymptotics for positive t in other words the zeros of the function behave like arithmetic progressions after passing a certain threshold e(c / t) where c is constant.He also found a more generalized Riemann--Siegel approximation

Comment: It seems unlikely that the zeta zero locations behave like an arithmetic progression. Can you provide a link to the Tao lecture?

Comment: OK, I think you're referring to https://youtu.be/t908N5gUZA0 What he says is that if you look at a small interval far out, e.g., between $T$ and $T+1$ for $T$ much larger than $1$, then the zeros in that interval will be evenly spaced – not *exactly* evenly, but close to evenly. But I think even that conclusion is conditional on the Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: In the cited lecture Terry Tao does not say that the zeros of the zeta function will be close to evenly spaced, nor did he say that the zeros behave like an arithmetic progression.  He said that the zeros behave in that (absurd) way *if* the de Bruijn–Newman is non-zero.  But the zeros are known to not behave in that absurd way, so this is a contradiction.  That is how Tao and Rodgers proved the de Bruijn–Newman constant equals zero.  The proof does not assume the Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: @DavidFarmer Excellent summary of the situation! A small correction - Tao and Rodgers only proved the constant is greater than or equal to 0, not exactly 0. (As it would have to be, given that their argument is unconditional of RH, because the constant being less than or equal to 0 is equivalent to RH).

Comment: @WillSawin Yes, thanks.  I should have said "...*if* the de Bruijn–Newman constant is negative." and later "...proved the de Bruijn–Newman constant is non-negative."